# What if I want the cross product to have a unit?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

This is a strange request, but still.

I encountered this kind of expression:
$$
v_1+v_2+v_1\times v_2
$$
If these were numbers, I would profitably rewrite this as
$$
(1+v_1)\times(1+v_2)-1
$$
but of course this is impossible: there is no nonzero vector $1$ with $1\times1=1$, let alone $1\times v=v\times1=v$ for all $v$.

Do you know of any kind of substitute for that? To be more specific, can one rewrite $v_1+v_2+v_1\times v_2$ as $x+y_1\times y_2$ where $y_i$ only depend on $v_i$ while $x$ does not depend on anything?

Comment: The first expression makes sense. Why you want to rewrite it and what has this to do with units ?

Comment: Cross product does not have regular properties we are accustomed to when dealing with multiplication. You may want to check Lie algebra. Cross product can be defined as Lie bracket operation in 3d vector space.